# Facebook connect with codeigniter to get email of user

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

i am using codeigniter library for facebook connect.
code for that

```
$access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
                $this->facebook->setAccessToken($access_token); 
                $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email,gender');
                print_r($profile);
```

i get all field except email.
how can i get email from that.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the `email` permission from user to get the email

FYI: [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)